# Can the word "program" be used to refer to the whole package of courses, facilities, people, funds, etc., in a certain discipline at a certain place?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a simple way (ideally, one or two words) to refer to each of the following items as elements of the same whole? Here are the items:

1. the courses for undergraduate, graduate, and PhD students in a certain discipline (say, mathematics) at a certain university;
2. the people teaching these courses or doing research in the same discipline at the same university;
3. the facilities (classrooms, labs, etc.) where these activities of teaching and research take place;
4. the funds (salaries, scholarships, etc.) that teachers, researchers, and students receive to support their activities.

I thought that "mathematics program" would have been fine for my purposes, but I'm no longer so sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an appropriate use of the word. The word program is quite general, meaning simply "a set of related measures or activities with a particular long-term aim". In this context, it could refer to any or all of the aspects mentioned in the question, but wouldn't necessarily refer to any one specifically without more context. A university that has an excellent mathematics program would be understood to have a high-quality course of study overall. That could include the instructors, the facilities, the curriculum, the funding, the alumni network, the job placement rate, or any other measure of quality.